# Heroku deploys my discord bot, but the it's commands don't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, discord.js

I am very tired, but basically, my discord bot on Heroku, after trying for a few hours, seems to be deploying fine acording to it's logs. I can't find anything wrong there, although when I try executing simple commands on my discord server, it doesn't seem to respond. It works fine when I run it localy on my PC, so I don't think the coding is the problem. Please help, if you need anything out of my bot's files, please just ask.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because of Dyno Sleep:

> If an app has a free web dyno, and that dyno
> receives no web traffic in a 30-minute period, it will
> sleep. In addition to the web dyno sleeping, the
> worker dyno (if present) will also sleep.

Also:

> Personal accounts are given a base of 550 free dyno hours each month

More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#dyno-sleeping

Comment: I am sorry, I am very new to this, but what exactly is a web dyno?

Comment: Every Heroku account is allocated a pool of free dyno hours

Comment: Your app will sleep if it doesn't receive any traffic in a 30-minute period. It will again wake when a new connection comes, **only after 5-10 seconds**. That's why your bot isn't responding.

Comment: In my suggestion, you can use Replit for hosting your bot

Comment: Well, the bot wasn't even starting to function... I don't know what happened. I deployed it multiple times, until I tested a different token, and it worked! So I though that the problem might have been the token that was wrong, but thinking about it, it would have said that the token was invalid. So I don't know what was up, but it is back to working, thank you for your attention!